# XRandr Refuses Custom Resolution

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, monitor, xrandr

I've got the exact timings I need for my monitor from CRU in Windows and they work great, in Windows. However, using XRandr and any of the currently available solutions on the forum never results in a mode being properly loaded.

```
[  1329.608] (WW) NVIDIA(0): No valid modes for
[  1329.608] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:Custom_1920x1080_87,DFP-4:Custom_1920x1080_87";
```

No matter what I try, the modes are refused. But I know for a fact the numbers are correct. I tried disabling all the NVIDIA checks in Xorg.Conf, that accomplished nothing. Is there an up-to-date tutorial or recommended solution on forcing specific custom resolutions with frequencies and timings?

Edit:

My custom-resolution.conf (Confirmed that it is being read)

```
    Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "BenQMonitor"
    Modeline "Custom_1920x1080_87" 191.4 1920 1944 1976 2000 1080 1083 1088 1100 +hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "Custom_1920x1080_87"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "BenQMonitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "Custom_1920x1080_87"
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "NoLogo" "True"
    Option "ModeValidation" "HDMI-0: NoEdidMaxPClkCheck, NoHorizSyncCheck, NoVertRefreshCheck, NoMaxSizeCheck, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, AllowNon60HzDFPModes, NoTot>
    Screen 0
EndSection
```

I tried fiddling with different ModeValidations, makes no difference. The clock timings are 100% correct, tested on win. From what I can tell, Xrandr is definitely reading what I'm putting down, and actively refusing it.

Comment: _What exactly_ did you try? If you don't show us what you tried, we will probably just end up suggesting the same things again

Comment: Edited. For some reason the code block overflows, but the data's there. That's a custom conf file I made that should by all means work.